# Suppose $A,B,C$ are sets. Prove that $A\mathbin\triangle B\subseteq C \iff A\cup C=B\cup C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A,B,C$ are sets.  Prove that $A\mathbin\triangle B\subseteq C \iff A\cup C=B\cup C$.

I proved that for $x\in A\setminus B$, $x\in A\cup C$ and for $x\in B\setminus A$, $x\in B\cup C$. How do I show that $A\cup C=B\cup C$, and that $A\mathbin\triangle B\subseteq C \iff A\cup C=B\cup C$?

Comment: To prove $x \ $  **iff**  $ \ y$ you need prove **two** things: 1. if $x$, then $y$ ; 2. if $y$, then $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Lets have our three sets:
[image: $A,B,C$]

We find $A\mathbin\triangle B$ as the elements in $A$ or in $B$ but not in both.
corresponding to the yellow area bellow:
[image: $A\mathbin\triangle B$]

Given that $A\mathbin\triangle B\subseteq C$, then the red area bellow is empty:
[image: $A\mathbin\triangle B\setminus C$]

So if we take $A\cup C$ minus the empty area (red above) we will get the green area below:
[image: $A\cup C$]

Which is the same result as if we get $B\cup C$, which proves:
$A\mathbin\triangle B\subseteq C\implies A\cup C=B\cup C$.

Now for the other way:

If $A\cup C=B\cup C$ then the red areas bellow must be empty:
[image: $(A\cup C)\mathbin\triangle(B\cup C)$]

When we substract these empty areas from the yellow areas from $A\mathbin\triangle B$ (bellow):
[image: $A\mathbin\triangle B$]
then the reminder is contained in $C$.

This proves that $A\cup C=B\cup C\implies A\mathbin\triangle B\subseteq C$.

Comment: What software did you use for the Venn diagrams? Also, aren't using them considered as a not rigorous proof?

Comment: @kuhaku I used Inkscape. I'm not sure if this apply as a rigorous proof. The one qualifying the proof should define what is rigorous enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show that every $x\in A\cup C$ is also in $B\cup C$, other way is symmetrical. Assume $x\in A\cup C$. If $x\in C$ then it is in $B\cup C$. Then assume $x\in A$. If $x\in A$ but not in $B$ then $x\in C$ from $A\Delta B \subseteq C$. Then assume $x\in A\cap B$. Then $x\in B$ and therefore $x\in B\cup C$. $\square $

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A\mathop\Delta B\subseteq C$ is equivalent to
$$ \tag1\forall x\colon((x\in A\land x\notin B)\lor (x\notin A\land x\in B))\to x\in 
C$$and $ A\cup C=B\cup C$ to
$$ \tag2\forall x\colon (x\in A\lor x\in C)\leftrightarrow(x\in B\lor x\in C).$$
One way to prove that(1) and (2) are equivalent is to write down the 8-row truth table for both.

Answer (score 0):

If one uses $+$ for symmetric difference and multiplication for intersection, then $A\cup C=A+C+AC$. Also, $X\subseteq Y$ if and only if $XY=X$. We are in the boolean ring of subsets of $A\cup B\cup C$, so we can use the usual algebraic rules (keeping also into account that $X+X=0$ (the empty set).

\begin{align}
A+B\subseteq C
&\iff
(A+B)C=A+B\\
&\iff
AC+BC=A+B\\
&\iff
A+AC=B+BC\\
&\iff
A+C+AC=B+C+BC
\end{align}