# Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. Prove that $A △ B ⊆ C \iff A ∪ C = B ∪ C$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

This is Velleman's exercise 3.5.20 (**And NO, not a duplicate of** "[Suppose $A,B,C$ are sets. Prove that $A\mathbin\triangle B\subseteq C \iff A\cup C=B\cup C$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601903/suppose-a-b-c-are-sets-prove-that-a-mathbin-triangle-b-subseteq-c-iff-a-cup)" or "[Prove that $A∆B⊆C$ iff$ A∪C=B∪C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615081/prove-that-a%e2%88%86b%e2%8a%86c-iff-a%e2%88%aac-b%e2%88%aac)", *my question is different*):

> Suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. Prove that $A\,\triangle\,B \subseteq C \iff A \cup C = B \cup C$.

Here's my proof of it:

Proof.

($\rightarrow$) Suppose $A △ B ⊆ C$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A ∪ C$, which means either $x ∈ A$ or $x ∈ C$. If $x ∈ B$, then clearly $x ∈ B ∪ C$. If $x ∉ B$, then since  $x ∈ A$, we have $x ∈ A\setminus B$ and therefore $x ∈ A △ B$. From $A △ B ⊆ C$ and $x ∈ A △ B$, we get $x ∈ C$. From the two cases we have $x ∈ B ∪ C$ and since $x$ was arbitrary, $x ∈ A ∪ C \Rightarrow x ∈ B ∪ C$.

Now let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $B ∪ C$, which means either $x ∈ B$ or $x ∈ C$. If $x ∈ A$, then clearly $x ∈ A ∪ C$. If $x ∉ A$, then since  $x ∈ B$, we have $x ∈ B\setminus A$ and therefore $x ∈ A △ B$. From $A △ B ⊆ C$ and $x ∈ A △ B$, we get $x ∈ C$. From the two cases we have $x ∈ A ∪ C$ and since $x$ was arbitrary, $x ∈ A ∪ C \Leftarrow x ∈ B ∪ C$.

From $x ∈ A ∪ C \Rightarrow x ∈ B ∪ C$ and $x ∈ A ∪ C \Leftarrow x ∈ B ∪ C$, we get $x ∈ A ∪ C \iff x ∈ B ∪ C$ and therefore $A ∪ C = B ∪ C$. Thus, $A △ B ⊆ C \Rightarrow A ∪ C = B ∪ C$.

($\leftarrow$) Suppose $A ∪ C = B ∪ C$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A △ B$. Now we can consider two different cases:

Case 1. $x ∈ A\setminus B$, which means $x ∈ A$ but $x ∉ B$. From $x ∈ A$ and $x ∈ A ∪ C$, we get $x ∈ B ∪ C$. But since we saw that $x ∉ B$, thus $x ∈ C$.

Case 2. $x ∈ B\setminus A$, which means $x ∈ B$ but $x ∉ A$. From $x ∈ B$ and $x ∈ B ∪ C$, we get $x ∈ A ∪ C$. But since we saw that $x ∉ A$, thus $x ∈ C$.

Since from both cases we get $x ∈ C$ and since $x$ was arbitrary, then $x ∈ A △ B ⊆ C$ and therefore $A ∪ C = B ∪ C \Rightarrow A △ B ⊆ C$.

From ($\rightarrow$) and ($\leftarrow$), we get $A △ B ⊆ C \iff A ∪ C = B ∪ C$.$\square$

---

Now here is my question:

1. Is my proof valid? Particularly the first part (i.e. ($\rightarrow$)): in the first part, in the goal (i.e. the statement that we wanted to prove) there was a conjunction which I kind of ignored it **and proved "$x ∈ A ∪ C \Rightarrow x ∈ B ∪ C$" and "$x ∈ A ∪ C \Leftarrow x ∈ B ∪ C$" separately!** Is that correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot find a mistake. Btw if you have proved that $x\in A\cup C\implies x\in B\cup C$ on base of $A\triangle B\subseteq C$ then you have proved also that $x\in B\cup C\implies x\in A\cup C$ on base of $A\triangle B\subseteq C$. Just switch the letters $A,B$ and realize that $A\triangle B=B\triangle A$.

Comment: @drhab Is that justified in a formal proof?

Comment: I don't see any objections. There is only a switch of labels $A,B$. To stay complete at most you must add a justification of $A\triangle B=B\triangle A$.

Comment: What does $A \triangle B$ mean?

Comment: It means the symmetric difference of A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first part of the forward direction, you write "If $x\not\in B$, then since $x\in A$...". How do you know that $x\in A$? At this point you only know that $x\in A$ or $x\in C$. You could have additionally assumed $x\not\in C$ to get to this point, for if $x\in C$ then clearly $x\in B\cup C$.

The second part of the forward direction has a similar issue.

I would split between different cases in the forward direction. You know that $x\in A\cup C$. Thus it is more natural to split:

Case 1: $x\in A$. Then $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in A\cap B$.

Subcase 1: $x\in A\setminus B$. Then $x\in A\,\triangle\, B\subseteq C$ and hence $x\in B\cup C$.

Subcase 2: $x\in A\cap B$. Then $x\in B$ and hence $x\in B\cup C$.

Case 2: $x\in C$. Then $x\in B\cup C$.

And similarly for the second part of the forward direction.

I have no comments about the proof of the reverse direction. It's perfect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I truly appreciate your help. :)